# select() issue with a push server - c/c++

Tags: c, windows, unix, select

I'm writing a server in C ++ for both Windows and Unix systems.

A key feature of this server is that it must be able to receive and send network packets at any time. 
Specifically, the server must be able to send data to the client not only in response to their messages, but also be able to send packets to them asynch in push.

I'm having difficulty in implementing a solution that uses the `select()` function in the scenario described above. 
The solution I have currently implemented does not convince me at all and I think it can be implemented with better patterns/solutions.

I currently have a dedicated thread (selector) that performs the select by listening on events in the reading for the server socket (to accept new connections) and for the sockets connected to the server.

This is the main select() loop:

```
    if((sel_res_ = select(nfds_+1, &read_FDs_, NULL, &excep_FDs_, &sel_timeout)) > 0){
    if(FD_ISSET(serv_socket, &read_FDs_)){
        //we have to handle a newly connection.
        ...
        if(sel_res_ > 1){
            //in addition to the newly connection, there is also some other message incoming on client sockets.
            ...
        }
    }else{
        //we have to handle incoming messages on client sockets
        ...
    }
}
```

This solution works well for receiving the data and to respond to client requests in synchronous form. 
However, the server must also be able to send asynchronous data, and send when necessary, packets in push.

To do this I currently use separate threads that perform directly the `send()` on the client sockets.

This solution does not convince me, and I would like to centralize the packets receiving and sending on the selector thread.

The main difficulty is that the `select()` by its nature is blocking and I have no control until a client does not send any packet or the timeout is triggered. 
The solution to set a timeout very low does not convince me; I see it as an easy solution that is actually doing active wait, and not only, however, the worst case I would pay the price of the timeout before sending the push packet.

I thought a more 'elegant' solution; I think, will work well, but only for a Unix/Linux platform. 
I thought to use an anonymous pipe and insert into the `select()` read_FDs_ the anonymous pipe read descriptor. 
In this way, when a thread wants to send a data in push, it writes something on this pipe, interrupting the `select()` and returning control to the selector that can then predispose to send the data to the client, without significant loss of time.
I think that this solution, unfortunately, cannot be implemented on Windows because the `select()` function on that system works only with fds that are actually sockets.

So the question is: Is there some well known solution that can be used to address this kind of scenario (both Linux and Windows)?

Comment: Use two threads, one for reading and one for writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a self connected UDP socket, this works equally well on Windows and Linux.

Basically, you create a UDP socket, `bind()` it to `INADDR_LOOPBACK` and port 0, and `connect()` it to itself (with the address taken from `getsockname()`).

At this point, you can send yourself a single byte message (or something more specific) to wake yourself up.